# Cannot set conditional/hit count/location breakpoint anymore

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, conditional-breakpoint

For some reason, conditional breakpoints suddenly became disabled in one of my project. I'm having a hard time to find any documentation on internet on the potential conditions that could disable these options. Anyone know why it became disabled, and how to fix it?

[image: Conditional breakpoints disabled]

Here are some information:

- It's a C# solution with about 50 C# projects, and a few shared projects and C++ projects (No project added/removed recently)
- I use Resharper 8 on Visual Studio 2013 with Update 4
- Closing/reopening Visual Studio didn't solve the problem

Comment: Is this for existing break points only, or also when you add new ones? Did you try to delete the `.suo` file and re-opened Visual Studio after that?

Comment: No it is for every breakpoints, existing and new ones. The weird thing is that it happened to a coworker the day after it happened to me. However, removing the `.suo` file fix the issue (I removed the `.sdf` as well), thanks!